# ¿Dónde y cómo implementar sqlite3_trace_v2 si sqlite3_trace está deprecado en Swift 3?

Tags: xcode, sqlite, swift3

Acabo de implementar la librería de SQLite.swift en mi aplicación; ésta funciona correctamente y sin problemas, excepto que Xcode da la advertencia de que la función sqlite3_trace en la clase Connection.swift está deprecada.

Por su parte, leyendo en foros e issues de esta librería, dicen que debe aplicarse la función sqlite3_trace_v2 pero no dicen cómo debe hacerse puesto que si solo se cambiara el nombre en el archivo de la clase, se genera una buena cantidad de errores que impide la ejecución de la aplicación.

De igual forma hay otro error que reporta Xcode luego de la importación de SQLite.swift y ese es

"/Users/developer/Desktop/domus/SQLite.swift/:1:1: Umbrella header for module 'SQLite' does not include header 'sqlite3.h'"

Y de ese no hay ninguna documentación actualmente en la web.

A continuación una captura de los errores que reporta xCode
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradecería una respuesta que pudiera o bien permitir el reemplazo exitoso de sqlite3_trace a sqlite3_trace_v2 o bien quitar la advertencia.

Muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

La advertencia ***'sqlite3_trace' is deprecated*** es inofensiva.

> Debió desaparecer a partir de iOS 10.0, pero no ocurrió debido a una deprecation realizada con ***__attribute__((deprecated))*** en vez de la forma estandar ***@available***.

En otras palabras, es poco probable que modifiquen el código fuente del framework por lo cual seguirá apareciendo la advertencia. Tampoco se recomienda modificar el framework internamente ni agregar headers o clases adicionales, no obstante, hay dos formas de ocultarla utilizando Pods, dado su caracter inofensivo:

1.Ocultar advertencias de SQLite especificamente (Recomendada)

```
platform :ios, '10.3'

target 'MyApp' do

pod 'SQLite.swift', '~> 0.11', :inhibit_warnings => true

end
```

2.Ocultar TODAS las advertencias de este tipo

```
platform :ios, '10.3'
inhibit_all_warnings!

target 'MyApp' do

pod 'SQLite.swift', '~> 0.11'

end
```